How to create an Excel table from non-structured text using text formatting as the delimeter
I am trying to extract most of the information found on a government website (CFIA-CFIT Part I and Part II) and create a table in excel. This table is to have three columns; ID, Name, and Detail. The ID and Name are bolded while the details are unbolded and begin with "is the..." as seen in the image below

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated as manually inputting this data would be extremely inefficient. Not to mention this information is likely to be updated so I would need to be able to have recreate/update the table periodically.
I have tried to create a table  by extracting the data from a pdf of this whole page into excel, by getting data from web link, and I tried to remove all tabs between sentences so that the text is one large string. I can get the data into excel but have been unsuccessful in creating a table which follows the format seen below.



ID
Name
Details




1-100-001
Alfalfa-grass hay sun-cured ground (or alfalfa-grass meal)
is the product that consists.....


1-100-002
Alfalfa hay sun-cured ground (or sun-cured alfalfa meal)
is the product that consists....


1-100....
Alfalfa leaves....
is the product....



The farthest I could get was using the data which had all tabs removed creating one large string. I tied to import this block of text into excel however, it lost the bolding on the text which I was going to use as part of the separation process.
This too was ultimately unsuccessful and I am at an impasse.

You need to use Microsoft Word.
Copy the text to the new document and insert the 3 columns 1 row table at the end.

Alt+F11 and insert this macro into a new module:
Sub Macro3()
  Dim par As Paragraph, r As Long, s As String, a As String, i As Long
  r = 0
  For Each par In Selection.Paragraphs
    If par.Range.Font.Bold Then
      ActiveDocument.Range.Tables(1).Rows.Add
      If r > 0 Then ActiveDocument.Range.Tables(1).Rows(r).Cells(3).Range = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
      r = r + 1
      a = par.Range
      i = InStr(a, " ")
      ActiveDocument.Range.Tables(1).Rows(r).Cells(1).Range = Left(a, i - 1)
      ActiveDocument.Range.Tables(1).Rows(r).Cells(2).Range = Mid(a, i + 1)
      s = ""
    Else
      s = s & Chr(10) & par.Range
    End If
  Next
  ActiveDocument.Range.Tables(1).Rows(r).Cells(3).Range = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
End Sub

Then select the text and run the macro.

